# Finding unregistered students

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables
**Table 1 add_students**

```
id  surname other_name  tel email   index_no    level
29   a                                           1
30   b                                           1
31   c                                           2
32   d                                           3
33   e                                           2
```

**Table 2 register_course**

```
id  student_id  course_id   date_reg    semester    academic_year
84  30              14      ########        1           2015/2016
85  30              10      ########        1           2015/2016
86  30              11      ########        1           2015/2016
87  31              68      ########        1           2015/2016
88  31              69      ########        1           2015/2016
89  31              70      ########        2           2015/2016
90  30              11      ########        2           2015/2016
91  31              68      ########        2           2015/2016
92  31              69      ########        2           2015/2016
93  31              70      ########        2           2015/2016
```

I used the following SQL to select students who have not registered  for say semester 2.

```
SELECT * from register_course 
right join add_student 
on  register_course.student_id = add_student.id 
WHERE register_course.student_id is   null 
and register_course.semester != '2'  
AND register_course.academic_year &gt;= '$yr' 
AND add_student.levels='1' 
AND  add_student.status = 'Active' 
group by add_student.id
```

The query returns 0 rows.

What I want are the students who have not registered for a particular semester and year.
  I will appreciate your help

Comment: Is the html table  for illustration of your database ?or are you trying to select values from a html table?

Comment: Is `&gt;= ` a typo here?

Comment: that is an illustration of my database

Comment: I suggest you create an sql fiddle with your table and query. Then we can take a look and _maybe_ help.

Comment: SQLFiddle(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4db8/3/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is OUTER JOIN the register_course TABLE with all the records you want exclude.

```
SELECT * FROM add_student 
LEFT JOIN register_course 
    ON  register_course.student_id = add_student.id 
    AND register_course.semester = '2' 
    AND register_course.academic_year &gt;= '$yr'  
WHERE register_course.student_id is   null 
AND add_student.levels='1' 
AND  add_student.status = 'Active' 
group by add_student.id
```

This method can be hard to understand so many people prefer to write it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM add_student 
WHERE  add_student.levels='1' 
  AND  add_student.status = 'Active' 
  AND register_course.student_id  NOT IN (
      Select student_id  FROM register_course WHERE semester = '2' 
      AND academic_year &gt;= '$yr';
  )
GROUP BY add_student.id
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I used register_course.id instead of register_course.student_id I got the result I am looking for